# MariaDB symbolic link using SaltStack

Tags: mariadb, symlink, salt-stack

I'm trying to use SaltStack to setup configuration on a MariaDB instance. I'm trying to make a symbolic link equivalent to this command

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/dbaas/mysql_client.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

Is that the right salt syntax ?

```
   link-mysql-client-cnf:
      file.symlink:
      - name: /etc/my.cnf
      - target: /var/lib/mysql/dbaas/mysql_client.cnf
      - force: True
```

For some reason the symlink fails because my.cnf already exists, I read the documentation and set Force to True but it didn't work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Just tested this with a file that exists and it works fine for me. Did you get any specific error messages?

Comment: I suspect that there is a permission problem. 

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 202 Sep 27 12:07 /etc/my.cnf

I think Salt runs in a root permission by default, right ?

Comment: yes it should do. I would suggest trying it manually first using `-f` to isolate any salt issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
What was causing the problem is that the engine was created before putting force=True and that was cached even when I modified the salt script. My advice is to clear out the engine and start-over by creating an engine and an instance anytime you change the salt.